# References in c++ with function

Tags: c++, c++11

Could anyone please elaborate the behaviour of reference in this code and why is it printing 12 in first line instead of 11.

Below is the code

http://ideone.com/l9qaBp

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int &fun()
{
    static int x = 10;
    x++;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr=&fun();
    int *ptr1=&fun();
    printf("%p  %p \t %d  %d",(void*)ptr,(void*)ptr1,*ptr,*ptr1);
    return 0;
}
```

the output of the code is

`134519132  134519132    12  12`

Please explain why **12** is getting printed on first call not **11** i understand when second call is made it should print 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error seems to be in thinking that `printf()` prints `*ptr` as soon as it comes available. It does not; `printf()` is not called until both `ptr` and `ptr1` are computed. Since both `ptr` and `ptr1` point to the same memory location, which is a static variable, and that location is updated after both the first call to `fun()` *and* the second, the address holds that value.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error in thinking that printf() prints *ptr as soon as it comes available.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why printf() is called after both the values are calculated

Comment: @Raghib Ahsan Because that's what kind of language C is. In C you describe what should happen so the order in what you type things is the order in which code is executed. Your printf is written after the statements executing the functions thus the values are calculated first and only then does your program read back the results and prints it.
Read wiki's page on C, and especially follow the link about imperative programming in the first sentence, if you want to learn more about this.
[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language))

Comment: @Nathilion; Actually question is C++ specific, but your comment is valid for C++ to.

Comment: `int *ptr=&fun();
    int *ptr1=&fun();` These lines doens't call the function does it I am thinking that these line are just giving the address of the function to pointer,function is being called in printf statement

Comment: Yes it calls the function and then assign the address of the returned referenced variable.

Comment: Of course they call the function. That's what operator() does. You're using two operators on the right-hand side of the assignment: '&' and '()' and by the rules of operator precedence first the function is executed and then the address of the resulting return value (your static 'x') is taking, which is then stored in the left-hand side of the assignment operator. If you really want the address of the function itself you have to use '&fun'. Note the lack of the '()' parentheses.

Comment: Aside from Nathilion's excellent point, even if `int *ptr=&fun()` didn't call the function (and it does) `printf()` would still not invoke the function itself, because that's not how `printf()` works. It expects "static" data to write, not "dynamic" function to call. If you want a print function that invokes another function, you'll have to roll your own, which isn't that hard actually; just pass a pointer to the function you want to invoke.

Comment: In particular, had you successfully assigned the address of `fun()` to `ptr` and `ptr1` (which would require a cast anyway, unless you change the type of `ptr` and `ptr1`), the `printf()` statement **as is** would simply print the data at the first address of `fun()` in memory.

Answer (score 4):

`ptr` and `ptr1` are pointing to the same variable `static int x`. The second call changed the value of `static int x` to `12`, then you print out the value by derefernce `ptr` and `ptr1`, the same result will be printed out.

Answer (score 3):

The int reference returned by fun() is the same for both calls (ref to the static x), hence the address of that reference is the same for both calls.  Hence the resulting dereference of that identical address is the current identical value.

Answer (score 0):

`static` variables have lifetime extent and are stored in statically allocated memory. It means that the storage of `static` local variables inside a function is not allocated and deallocated on call-stack.

Once `x` is initialized at compile time, the value of `x` is kept stored between the invocations of function `fun`.

As C++ statements are executed sequentially, `printf` will be executed after the invocations of two function calls in the given lines

```
int *ptr=&fun();
int *ptr1=&fun();
```

and therefore the value of `x` will be `12` before the execution of `printf` statements.

Keep in mind that

```
int *ptr=&fun();
int *ptr1=&fun();
```

is not equivalent to

```
int& (*ptr)() = &fun;
int& (*ptr1)() = &fun;
```

In second snippet `ptr` and `ptr1` both holding the address of function `fun`. In this case you need to call function directly or by using these pointers as

```
int a = ptr();
int b = ptr1();
```

after this invocation value of `a` and `b` will be `12`.